# Is there a way to read columns with strings as strings when using RGoogleDocs

Tags: r, google-docs, data-munging

I use RGoogleDocs a lot. I use it to read in data that is private or only shared with a few people. I know that `read.table` and `read.csv` allow one to use `stringsAsFactors=FALSE`.

I want to do something similar in RGoogleDocs. Here is my typical code

```
sheets.con <- getGoogleDocsConnection(getGoogleAuth("fjb@gmail.com", ps, service ="wise"))
spreadsheet <- getWorksheets("private spreadsheet",sheets.con)
first <- sheetAsMatrix(spreadsheet$"Sheet 1",header=TRUE, as.data.frame=TRUE, trim=TRUE) #Get one sheet
```

That almost always reads the character values as factors. I have been using data.table a lot lately and factors seem to make my data munging in data.table a bit bothersome. Is there an easy way to read the non-numeric columns as character vectors rather than as factors?

Comment: Why not add another line to fix this right after the read statement?

Comment: And what exactly is the bother?

Comment: I sometimes use something like `dat[sapply(dat, is.factor)] = lapply(dat[sapply(dat, is.factor)], as.character)` on `data.frame`s where I want to convert all of the factors to characters.

Comment: @MatthewDowle somewhere in my memory I have vague recollections of issues with unused levels of factors when adding new rows. Factors work well when one is at the statistical analysis phase but I have often found it to be a pain at the data pre-processing stage.

Comment: @Farrel I'm struggling to see what the question is.

Comment: @MatthewDowle. The question is "Is there a way to import Google Docs Spreadsheets into a data.table or into a data.frame such that columns with character values do not get converted to factors?" The RGoogleDocs package is to my knowledge the only currently working way to read straight from Google Docs into R. Maiasaura has recommended that I should simply add something such as that suggested by mrdwab above. I guess one line will not kill me. I was hoping that someone who was intimately familiar with RGoogleDocs package would add their 2c worth.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Duncan Temple Lang, the writer of RGoogleDocs updated the package to 0.7-0. He added `stringsAsFactors` to the `getWorksheets()` and `sheetAsMatrix()` function.

Here is how you can get it into your R.

```
   install.packages("devtools")
   library(devtools)
   install_github("RGoogleDocs", "duncantl")
```

Now my line is

```
   first <- sheetAsMatrix(spreadsheet$"Sheet 1",header=TRUE, as.data.frame=TRUE, trim=TRUE, stringsAsFactors=FALSE) #Get one sheet
```